# Assign to a variable data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, assign

I am trying to assign a column of data to a new column in an existing data frame. The data frame changes in a loop, from scores.d, to scores.e. My desired output is to have scores.X$new.col populated with the vals, where X is replaced with the current dfname.

```
dfnames <- c("d","e")
scores.d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10)
scores.e <- data.frame(x = 2, y = 10:20)
vals <- 60:70

for (i in seq_along(dfnames)){
   assign(get(paste0("scores.",dfnames[i]))$new.col,vals)
}

Error in assign(get(paste0("scores.", dfnames[i]))$new.col, vals) : 
  invalid first argument
```

This gives me an error, because assign is looking for a character string as the first argument, when I need it to include the column name. Simply adding $new.col to the paste command doesn't work (assume $ doesn't translate from string).

I am new to R and don't know the dos and don'ts of assigning things. I thought to make a list of data frames, then populate each with vals, but it didnt work as I am specifying particular columns, in my real data, the data frames are pre-existing anyway, I'm just trying to add to them here. Thoughts?

EDIT*
@Jason has provided an answer, by allocating the values to a temporary variable, then assigning it back. Works fine for my purposes, however I had tried it with a list of strings in place of creating the names via `paste0()`, and it still gave me the error. First, Jason's working answer:

```
dfnames <- c("d","e")
scores.d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10)
scores.e <- data.frame(x = 2, y = 11:20)
vals <- 61:70

for (i in dfnames){ #don't need seq_along

    dat<-get(paste0("scores.",i)) #pull up the data 
    dat$new.col<-vals
    assign(paste0('scores.',i),dat) #replace old data frame with new
}
```

Now with a list of names replacing the paste procedure (note the change to seq_along):

```
dfnames <- c("d","e")
scores.d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10)
scores.e <- data.frame(x = 2, y = 11:20)
vals <- 61:70

# for demonstrative purposes only, these were created in a loop in my code
full.dfnames[1] <- "Scores.d"
full.dfnames[2] <- "Scores.e"

for (i in seq_along(dfnames)){ #added seq_along back for the name index

    dat<-get(full.dfnames[i]) #pull up the data 
    dat$new.col<-vals
    assign(full.dfnames[i],dat) #replace old data frame with new
}

>Error in assign(get(paste0("scores.", dfnames[i]))$new.col, vals) : 
      invalid first argument
```

Comment: first, i think you'll want vals=60:69 to match the length of the x and y columns. second, do you want the effect of `scores.d$new.col=vals` and `scores.e$new.col=vals` but with speedier syntax - i assume this is part of a larger problem?

Comment: don't use `assign()` to create many vars. Instead learn how to work with lists and functional: https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/535931179556691968

Comment: @Dominik yes, this is part of a large script that does several calculations for several columns on two data frames. It is code that I've inherited and I'm trying to simplify it using my limited Matlab knowledge. Each "vals" will be some calculation unique to that iteration of scores.X.

Comment: @Metrics, thanks for the link, I will have a look. At the moment I am so pressed for time that I asked ere for a quick fix. I will devote some time to expanding my knowledge once I have some free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the following works though might not be as streamlined as you would like.

```
dfnames <- c("d","e")
scores.d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10)
scores.e <- data.frame(x = 2, y = 11:20)
vals <- 61:70

for (i in dfnames){ #don't need seq_along

    dat<-get(paste0("scores.",i)) #pull up the data 
    dat$new.col<-vals
    assign(paste0('scores.',i),dat) #replace old data frame with new

}
```

Comment: wonderful, thanks for the answer there. This is what I had attempted, I had a list of the names saved, and attempted to reference those but it persisted in giving me the invalid first argument error. See the additional example in my edited question.