# How to assign value to cell of data frame with variable name without intermediate variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame like the following, but the data frame name changes each time I want to do the following operation:

```
name <- "test"
type <- "test_type"
ACTUAL <- replicate(1,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE))

assign(paste(name, type, sep = ""), cbind(data.frame(replicate(10,sample(c(NA, 0, 1),1000,rep=TRUE))), ACTUAL))
```

The value in the 11th column is the correct value, and the first 10 columns are the prediction values (some NA values, as it wasn't predicted on every iteration). I want to add another column which tells me the proportion of the time which the prediction model was correct (ignoring NA value, as I didn't expect the model to predict on each sample every time).

I want to do something like the following, but it does not work:

```
for (x in 1:nrow(get(paste(name, type, sep = "")))) {
  get(paste(name, type, sep = ""))[x, "ACC"] <-
    as.character(rowMeans(get(paste(name, type, sep = ""))[x,-c(which(is.na(get(
      paste(name, type, sep = "")
    )[x, ])),
    grep("ACTUAL", colnames(get(
      paste(name, type, sep = "")
    ))),
    grep("names", colnames(get(
      paste(name, type, sep = "")
    ))))] == get(paste(name, type, sep = ""))[x, "ACTUAL"]))
}
```

Could you please suggest how to assign the accuracy value to this new column in the data frame with a variable name? `assign` doesn't work because I am assigning values to a noncharacter value.

I also cannot create an intermediate variable, as this is part of a much larger function and it is essential that variable names do not get confused when running the function on a parallel system with shared memory.

Thanks!

EDIT: I realized I should mention that the solution [Assign to a variable data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891156/assign-to-a-variable-data-frame-in-r) uses an intermediate variable, so I am specifically looking for a solution without an intermediate variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intermediate variables will not interfere if you isolate them within functions.  How about something along these lines?

1) Calculate the proportion of the time which the prediction model was correct, ignoring NA value.  This is a pure function with no side effects.

```
propCorrectPred <- function (df) {
  correctPredictions <- lapply(df[,-ncol(df)], function(x) x == df$ACTUAL)
  correctPredictions <- as.data.frame(correctPredictions)
  rowMeans(correctPredictions, na.rm = T)
}
```

2) Get the name of a data frame, and add an `ACC` column that contains the proportions calculated by `propCorrectPred`.  This is an impure function with side effects.  Note that it will not work as you expect if you run it with `sapply` instead of a `for` loop.

```
addACC <- function(df_name) {
  df <- get(df_name, envir = parent.frame())
  df$ACC <- propCorrectPred(df)
  assign(df_name, df, envir = parent.frame())
}
```

3) Loop over the names.

```
for (x in paste0(name, type)) {
  addACC(x)
}
```